# adding ssh key fails

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to configure git.

I first removed the complete git directory using `rm -rf ~./git`.

And then added my account and email with below command

```
git config --global user.name "YOUR NAME"
git config --global user.email "YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS"
```

After this I added `ssh` key by following this [link](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/).

Even after following all these while I go to clone any app, I am getting below error

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure about the path being `~./git`?

Comment: yes. I confirmed with this `ls -la |  grep .git*
`

Comment: `~/.git` and `~./git` are not the same.

Comment: yeah, but I am sure my git is in that location.

Comment: First things first: `ssh -vvv git@github.com` to identify where is the problem lying.

Answer (score 0):

#### Create a SSH config file

> When you have multiple identity files, create a SSH config file mechanisms to create aliases for your various identities.
>
> You can construct a SSH config file using many parameters and different approaches.
>
> The format for the alias entries use in this example is:
>
> ```
> Host alias 
>   HostName bitbucket.org 
>   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
> ```
>
> To create a config file for two identities (workid and personalid), you would do the following:

```
Open a terminal window.
Edit the ~/.ssh/config file.
```

If you don't have a config file, create one.
Add an alias for each identity combination for example:

```
Host workid
HostName bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/workid

Host personalid
HostName bitbucket.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personalid
```

---

#### Note:

You will need to add the keys to your server user account as well.